# Edit a single address in Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

I've read [the docs](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/customer-address-management) but I can't seem to get this to work properly. I want to edit a single address on a separate page from where all addresses for a customer are listed. I have the link to the edit page, which looks like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('account/edit-address') }}?addressId={{ address.id }}">Edit</a>
```

Then on that edit-address template I have the following:

```
{% set addressId = craft.request.getParam('addressId') %}

<form method="post">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/customerAddresses/save">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="account/address-book">

    {% if addressId %}
        <input type="hidden" name="address[id]" value="{{ addressId }}">
    {% endif %}

    <input type="text" name="address[firstName]" value="{{ address ? address[firstName] : '' }}">
    <input type="text" name="address[lastName]" value="{{ address ? address[lastName] : '' }}">
</form>
```

That leads to a "Variable 'address' does not exist" error. I understand why I get that error but I'm not sure how to get the value field to show the address info. Having a blank form field isn't going to cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? The second example will ensure an address variable exists, even if it is set to null.

`{% set address = craft.commerce.customer.address(addressId) %}`

or

`{% set address = address is defined ? address : null %}`

As for accessing the data, you would just do this:

`{{ address ? address.firstName : '' }}`

Another way to do it (without needing to define a null address variable) is:

`{{ address.firstName ?? '' }}`

Comment: Yes! Thanks Luke - I wasn't sure how to set the address variable exactly.